# Get endpoint from CreateDBInstanceResponse class in AWS RDS .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I have the following method:

```
public string Add(string tenant, string databaseName, string username, string password)
        {
            using (var client = new AmazonRDSClient())
            {
                var instance = new CreateDBInstanceRequest();
                instance.DBInstanceIdentifier = tenant;
                instance.DBInstanceClass = DefaultMysqlSettings.DBInstanceClass;
                instance.AllocatedStorage = DefaultMysqlSettings.AllocatedStorage;
                instance.DBName = databaseName;
                instance.Engine = DefaultMysqlSettings.Engine;
                instance.EngineVersion = DefaultMysqlSettings.EngineVersion;
                instance.MasterUsername = username;
                instance.MasterUserPassword = password;
                instance.LicenseModel = DefaultMysqlSettings.LicenseModel;
                instance.Port = DefaultMysqlSettings.Port;
                instance.AutoMinorVersionUpgrade = true;
                CreateDBInstanceResponse response = client.CreateDBInstance(instance);

                return tenant;
            }
        }
```

How can i get the endpoint from "CreateDBInstanceResponse"?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inspect the response of the call to CreateDBInstance that you made.

The [CreateDBInstanceResponse](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/TRDSCreateDBInstanceResponse.html) object contains a property [DBInstance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/TRDSDBInstance.html). This class contains a property [Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/TRDSEndpoint.html). Your DB Cluster's endpoint is contained in this object.

It may be the case that the endpoint is not immediately available in this response; if so, you can use the DBClusterIdentifier that returned as a property of DBInstance to poll [DescribeDBClusters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/RDS/MRDSRDSDescribeDBClustersDescribeDBClustersRequest.html) until the endpoint is available.